# Laravel Passport returns unauthenticated on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, laravel-artisan, laravel-passport, unauthorized

I am using Laravel 5.7 and I installed Passport 6.0 for API authentication.

When I am running `php artisan serve` and use that URL, then Passport authenticate my request but when I deploy it on a server, it always unauthenticate my request.

I am using AWS server with Ubuntu 18.04

I have also tried:

`php artisan passport:keys`

`php artisan optimize:clear`

as well as cleared all cache and config.

Comment: I have enhanced the formatting of the question and added code quotes. Maybe you should add more information about the hosting environment, e.g. what version of Ubuntu?